# Cannot build an Ionic iOS app using Azure devops

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, azure-devops

I'm having a hard time building my iOS application and generating IPA file through Azure devOps pipeline. On my Mac I'm able to run `ionic cordova build ios --release` command and automatically sign the app through Xcode but I get lots of errors from the pipeline.

Steps: Install apples certificates and provisioning profile (these are the ones automatically generated by Xcode on my local machine), run build command (`ionic cordova build ios --release --developmentTeam="XXXX"`) and I get the `Command failed with exit code 65` error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IRLScannerViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Scan.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **
```

I also tried switching from the build command to an Xcode task with autocatically signing but I also get an error: `AppName has conflicting provisioning settings. AppName is automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified.`

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get rid of the Xcode build erros adding a prior CMD job: `sed -i '' 's/iPhone Distribution/iPhone Developer/g' platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig`